# How to break in c++ code called from c# interop

Tags: c#, c++, debugging, interop, visual-studio-2019

Working with Visual Studio 2019. Calling c functions from c# is common but when there is a runtime error, I get a popup window as such:

[image: runtime error]

I would like however to actually break into the c++ code so I can debug it,in particular review the call stack, watch the local variables, add break points etc.

How to achieve this ?

If one need a demo project:
https://github.com/mprevot/InteropDemo

I'm calling a c function designed to fail:

```
#ifndef Pinvoke
#define Pinvoke extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
#endif

std::wstring ToString(int number)
{
    std::wstringstream s;
    s << "got number " << number;
    return s.str();
}

Pinvoke auto GetNumbers() -> void
{
    std::vector<int> array0{11,12,13,14};
    std::vector<int> array1{21,22,23};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        ToString(array0[i]);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        ToString(array1[i]);
}
```

I call such function from c#:

```
internal static class NativeLibCall
{
    public const string _dll = "NativeLib.dll";

    [DllImport(_dll, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    internal static extern void GetNumbers();
}

public class NativeLibInterop
{
    public void GetNumbers() => NativeLibCall.GetNumbers();
}
```

Comment: You need to use mixed-mode debugging: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-in-mixed-mode?view=vs-2019&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003493

Comment: That's how asserts work in C/C++ code.  Fairly important it works that way since you commonly do not have source code to look at when the assert fails, so couldn't tell what went wrong.  As noted by the dialog, you have to click the Retry button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Kevin Gosse, and detailed in [MSFT documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-in-mixed-mode?view=vs-2019&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003493), just enable **mixed-mode debugging**:

> Enable mixed-mode debugging for a managed calling app
>
> 1. Select the C# or Visual Basic project in Solution Explorer and select the Properties icon, press Alt+Enter, or right-click and choose
>    Properties.
> 2. Select the Debug tab, and then select Enable native code debugging.
> 3. Close the properties page to save the changes.